# Why are arguments in JavaScript not preceded by the var keyword?

Tags: javascript

This may be a silly question, but why are function arguments in JavaScript not preceded by the var keyword?

Why:

```
function fooAnything(anything) {
  return 'foo' + anyThing;
}
```

And not:

```
function fooAnything(var anything) {
  return 'foo' + anyThing;
}
```

I have a feeling the answer is `because that's what the Spec says` but still...

Comment: Why do you want the keyword there? `var` declares variables, parameters are (a bit) different. There is no point of the keyword there, it adds no value.

Comment: isn't that a reason good enough? what additional information will var give you? besides, you save 4 chars everytime you declare a function var which you can put on making the variable name longer for clarity :).

Comment: Because ECMA-262 says formal parameters, like declared variables, are made named properties of the local variable object before any code is executed. So a formal parameter is more or less declared by default.

Comment: It's not "because that's what the Spec says" - there is a reason why the spec says that: because it makes sense to do it that way. Requiring "var" would be redundant, and making it optional would be confusing. (JavaScript does have some other features that in my opinion are pretty arbitrary and fall into the "because that's what the spec says" category.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be a redundant use of the `var` keyword. Items that appear in the parentheses that follow a function name declaration are explicitly parameters for the function.

Answer (score 9):

Most dynamicaly-typed programming languages *don't* have explicit vars in the argument list.  The purpose of the var keyword is to differentiate between "I am setting an existing variable" and "I am creating a new variable" as in

```
var x = 17; //new variable
x = 18; //old variable
```

(Only few languages, like Python, go away with the var completely but there are some issues with, for example, closures and accidental typos so var is still widespread)

But in an argument list *you cannot assign to existing variables* so the previous ambiguity *does not need to be resolved*. Therefore, a var declaration in the arguments list would be nothing more then redundant boilerplate. (and redundant boilerplate is bad - see COBOL in exibit A)

---

You are probably getting your idea from C or Java but in their case type declarations double up as variable declarations and the cruft in the argument lists is for the types and *not* for the declarations.

We can even get away with a "typeless, varless" argument list in some typed languages too. In Haskell, for example, types can be inferred so you don't need to write them down on the argument list. Because of this the argument list consists of just the variable names and as in Javascript's case we don't need to put the extraneous "let" (Haskell's equivalent to  "var") in there:

```hs
f a b =  --arguments are still variables,
         -- but we don't need "let" or type definitions
   let n = a + b in  --extra variables still need to be declared with "let"
   n + 17
```

Comment: This is a great answer, why isn't it getting any love :(

Comment: "But in an argument list you cannot assign variables" - some languages do allow you to assign defaults in the argument list (which apply if parameters aren't provided by the caller), but even if JavaScript allowed that we still wouldn't need `var` at the beginning of the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

The `var` keyword declares the scope of the variable. A function argument also introduces the scope for that argument. Hence there's no need for it, since it serves the same function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question comes up because we're used to seeing `function bla (int i)` in many languages. The same, syntactically, as the `int i;` somewhere in the function body to declare a variable. The two `int`s are however not doing the same; the first defines the type, the second defines type and the scope. If you don't have to declare the type, the scope-declaration still needs to happen (which is why we have `var` in the second case) but there is no information needed in front of arguments.